# reverse_iterator weird behavior with 2D arrays

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reverse-iterator

I have a 2D array. It's perfectly okay to iterate the rows in forward order, but when I do it in reverse, it doesn't work. I cannot figure out why.

I'm using MSVC v143 and the C++20 standard.

```cpp
int arr[3][4];
for (int counter = 0, i = 0; i != 3; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j != 4; ++j) {
        arr[i][j] = counter++;
    }
}

std::for_each(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](auto const& row) {
    for (auto const& i: row) {
        fmt::print("{} ", i);
    }
    fmt::print("\n");
});

std::for_each(std::rbegin(arr), std::rend(arr), [](auto const& row) {
    for (auto const& i: row) {
        fmt::print("{} ", i);
    }
    fmt::print("\n");
});
```

The output for the first `for_each` is fine:

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
```

Yet the second one is garbage:

```
-424412040 251 -858993460 -858993460
-424412056 251 -858993460 -858993460
-424412072 251 -858993460 -858993460
```

When I print their addresses up I couldn't understand it:

```
<Row addr=0xfbe6b3fc58/>
0 1 2 3
<Row addr=0xfbe6b3fc68/>
4 5 6 7
<Row addr=0xfbe6b3fc78/>
8 9 10 11
<Row addr=0xfbe6b3fb98/>
-424412040 251 -858993460 -858993460
<Row addr=0xfbe6b3fb98/>
-424412056 251 -858993460 -858993460
<Row addr=0xfbe6b3fb98/>
-424412072 251 -858993460 -858993460
```

What is happening here?

Comment: What if you remove the reference from variable i ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very likely a code generation bug of MSVC related to pointers to multidimensional arrays: The `std::reverse_iterator::operator*()` hidden in the range-based loop is essentially doing a `*--p`, where `p` is a pointer type to an `int[4]` pointing to the end of the array. Decrementing and dereferencing in a single statement causes MSVC to load the address of the local variable `p` instead of the address of the previous element pointed to by the decremented `p`, essentially resulting in the address of the local variable `p` being returned.

You can observe the problem better in the following standalone example (https://godbolt.org/z/x9q5M74Md):

```
#include <iostream>

using Int4 = int[4]; // To avoid the awkward pointer-to-array syntax
int arr[3][4] = {};

Int4 & test1()
{
  Int4 * p = arr;
  Int4 * pP1 = p + 1;

  // Works correctly
  --pP1;
  Int4 & deref = *pP1;
  return deref;
}

Int4 & test2()
{
  Int4 * p = arr;
  Int4 * pP1 = p + 1;

  // msvc incorrectly stores the address of the local variable pP1 (i.e. &pP1) in deref
  Int4 & deref = *--pP1;
  return deref;
}


int main()
{
  std::cout << "arr   = 0x" << &arr[0][0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "test1 = 0x" << &test1() << std::endl; // Works
  std::cout << "test2 = 0x" << &test2() << std::endl; // Bad
}
```

In this example, `&test1()` correctly prints the address of the first element of `arr`. But `&test2()` actually prints the address of the *local* variable `test2::pP1`, i.e. it prints `&test2::pP1`. MSVC even warns that `test2()` returns the address of the local variable `pP1` (C4172).
clang and gcc work fine. Versions before MSVC v19.23 also compile the code correctly.

Looking at the assembly output, clang and gcc emit the same code for `test1()` and `test2()`. But MSVC is doing:

```
; test1()
mov     rax, QWORD PTR pP1$[rsp]
mov     QWORD PTR deref$[rsp], rax

; test2()
lea     rax, QWORD PTR pP1$[rsp]
mov     QWORD PTR deref$[rsp], rax
```

Notice the `lea` instead of the `mov` statement, meaning that `test2()` loads the address of `pP1`.

MSVC seems to get confused somehow by pointers to multidimensional array.

Comment: I see. A possible workaround is to use the so-verbose `std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 3>`. I only used it if I wanted something like that in my API. Now I have another reason ... if I want to catch up with the fancy C++ 20 range adaptors! ;)

Comment: Excellent analysis .. :)

Comment: This looks a a serious bug in the compiler. Did you fill in a report?? It is actually failing to correctly compile simple standard code